# Using values of a custom object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have the following as part of my entity framework class:-

```
public   CustomerDetails GetCustomer(int id) {

        var customerDetails = entities.AccountDefinitions
       .Where(a => a.ORG_ID == id)
       .Select(cd => new CustomerDetails
       {
             AD = cd,
             SD = cd.SDOrganization,
             AA = cd.SDOrganization.AaaPostalAddresses,
             SN = cd.SiteDefinitions,
             Ar = cd.SiteDefinitions.SelectMany(a => a.DepartmentDefinitions.SelectMany(a2 => a2.SDUsers.Select(a3 => a3.AaaUser)))
       })
       .SingleOrDefault();
       return customerDetails;
        }
```

Inside the inner .Select I have five assignments operations, but since some assignments depend upon the other so how I can write something such as:-

```
Ar = SN.SelectMany(…….)
```

So in this way I will only query the database only one time to retrieve the cd.SiteDefenitions??

Comment: I think that you can use the [Include method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) like `SN = cd.SiteDefinitions.Include("DepartmentDefinitions.SDUsers.AaaUser"),` so that the query for the first reference will also retrieve the data that is needed by the second reference so that a second query to the database is not necessary.  I would verify that, though.

Comment: entity framework create a lot of unanswered questions , and you got confused on how your query will be performed. I use to do all the stuff using stored procedures on the database, and things were much clear. and you feel safer since you are sure which data exactly will be transferred to the client

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to do it like this:

```
var customerDetails = entities.AccountDefinitions
    .Where(a => a.ORG_ID == id)
    .Select(cd => new CustomerDetails
    {
        AD = cd,
        SD = cd.SDOrganization,
        AA = cd.SDOrganization.AaaPostalAddresses,
        SN = cd.SiteDefinitions
   })
   .SingleOrDefault();

if (customerDetails != null)
{
    customerDetails.Ar = customerDetails.SN...
}

return customerDetails;
```

I know it may not be quite what you were looking for, but you're not going to be able to `get` at the `SN` property during the parameterless constructor operation like that (AFAIK).

Comment: so is it a bad practice to do multiple queries to the database to initiate a class, rather than re-using the data that already exists in the memory.

Comment: @JohnPeter, it would always be better to make one round-trip, though this can be debated. I would say in your scenario, to ensure that the code **scales** as the database scales, don't make two round-trips and set `Ar` after the object is initialized.

Comment: so the only option will be is to follow your approach ?

Comment: @JohnPeter, that's probably not the case as there is always more than one way to get something done. As I stated at the beginning of my answer, this is one option.